# Remove DOM Elements in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, contenteditable

I am trying to create a component which can be edited. It is something like this:

```
<div contentEditable={true}>
  <OtherComponent />
</div>
```

I have a JSON which contains text and is rendered on the screen using this component. When I add a new paragraph in that text, DOM automatically creates a `p` tag with that paragraph's text. On click of save button, I save that newly added text in the JSON and call the `setState` method so that now the JSON can be re-rendered with the new text. On re-render, I do the see the new text, but I see it twice. Turns out, when the DOM has earlier created a `p` tag, React doesn't remove it on re-render. I don't want the old text to still appear on the page.

I read somewhere that when React re-renders the component (when we do `setState`), it only re-renders the nodes in its virtual DOM. The nodes which are created otherwise (like the `p` tag in my case), are not touched by React.

Is there some way I can have a solution to my problem and not see the same text twice?

Comment: looks like a state issue can you show us your `setState()`?

Comment: @antoineso is right; we'll need a [minimal-working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/17423) (the smallest reasonable piece of code we can use to reproduce the problem) to help out.